# Trouble with "URLs must include" with Sphider Search Engine

Tags: php, regex, search, search-engine, sphider

I'm using [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu).

I want to allow Spider to leave my domain http://www.example.com but only crawl/visit urls containing `example`. Means only urls like http://www.example.com or http://www.my-example.com or http://www.test.example.com should get visited/indexed but NOT http://www.exa-mple.com.

After reading the [manual](http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php#mustinc) I tried the following: [Screenshot of what I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YmnW.png)

But I'm getting this message when trying to index: [Image: What I'm getting when trying to index.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT2yJ.png)

Who can help me. What am I doing wrong? I also already tried `*example*` but this also didn't work.

Comment: You just need `*/example/`, but if you are not interested in checking the context, why not use a simple word `example` in the must include list?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your comment. I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php#mustinc) contains a misleading example:

> Every string starting with a `'*'` in front is considered as a regular expression, so that `'*/[a]+/'` denotes a string with one or more a's in it.

The `[...]` is a **character class** that matches any single character from a set/range defined inside it.

You can use a `*/example/` to define a regex that matches an `example` string.
However, if you are not interested in checking the context, you might as well use an `example` string in the must include list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me very much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*example)https?:\/\/\S+$
```

you can try this .
demo test here https://regex101.com/r/LUkHsD/3